# How to install pip associated to different versions of Python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, python-2.x

Currently, I am running two versions of `python` on Mac. The native one (2.7.10) (`/usr/bin/python`), and another one, which has been downloaded via `home-brew` (`2.7.14`).

I want to download two versions of `pip` and download packages depending on the python version I want to use.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, just take a look at [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It allows you to maintain multiple python environments and their packages in parallel. With the `-p` argument you can select the interpreter to be used for a particular environment.

Comment: @a_guest Ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Start by checking your available Python interpreters on your command line:

```
[root@server ~]# ls /usr/bin/ | grep python
python2 -> python2.6
python2.6
python3 -> python3.4
python3.4
```

Then download and run [this](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=0ahUKEwjH66edoMPWAhWdOsAKHU1kBoEQFghhMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbootstrap.pypa.io%2Fget-pip.py&usg=AFQjCNE8Fo9j_sgo1hBzEoUT39H85hFDrg) file using each interpreter

```
[root@server ~]# python2.6 get-pip.py
[root@server ~]# python3.4 get-pip.py
```

Then once both Python interpreters have the`pip` module installed, you can install packages to your specific Python interpreters using the following commands:

```
[root@server ~]# python2.6 -m pip install <module>
[root@server ~]# python3.4 -m pip install <module>
```

Comment: Ok, great! I will try it! Thanks.

Comment: For Python 3.6.5 command: `$ python3.6 -m pip install <module>` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning (for Windows Users), once you have multiple versions of Python installed, you can easily manage packages for each specific version by calling `pip<major>.<minor>` from a cmd window.

for example, I have Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7 currently installed, and I can manage my packages for each installation using pip2.7, pip3.6 and pip3.7 respectively ...

On Windows 10, `$ pip3.7 install <module>` works for me - haven't tested it with `venv` instances yet though